# scheme listing sucessive averages in reverse

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I am trying to list sucessive averages of elements in a list in reverse, for example in a list of (1 2 3) i try to get (3+2+1/3 2+1/2 1) here is an example of a list i tried my code on.

```
(list 2 3 4 5 6)
```

For some reason the values returned are " (4 7/2 4 7/2 4)". This is the code

```
(define (sucessive-avg lst)  
(if (=(length lst) 1)
lst
(cons(avg(reverse lst)) (sucessive-avg(cdr(reverse lst))))))
```

The problem does not come from my avg so i dont know what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@coredump's answer is a pretty good start but it doesn't use proper tail recursion and it looks like it's averaging the wrong parts of the list

> for example in a list of (1 2 3) i try to get (3+2+1/3 2+1/2 1)

For a list of `'(2 3 4 5 6)` my answer will give you

```
'((avg '(2 3 4 5 6))
  (avg '(2 3 4 5))
  (avg '(2 3 4))
  (avg '(2 3))
  (avg '(2)))
```

This seems to match your description more accurately.

Here's the code

```
(define (avg lst)
  (/ (foldl + 0 lst)
     (length lst)))

(define (successive-avg lst)
  (define (iter res lst)
    (if (empty? lst)
        (reverse res)
        (iter (cons (avg lst) res) (rest lst))))
  (iter '() (reverse lst)))

(print (successive-avg '(2 3 4 5 6)))
```

Output

```
'(4 3 1/2 3 2 1/2 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

How many times will you call reverse? Try to do a step-by-step execution of your code to understand what is going on.

You could write a function which collect averages for the successives CDRs of a list, and call it with a reversed list:

```
(define (successive-averages lst)
  (if (null? lst)
    lst
    (cons (avg lst)
          (successive-averages (rest lst))))

(successive-averages (reverse (list 2 3 4 5 6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to recall reverse or average at all. The reason you don't need average is that you can keep a running sum (in my code via a lambda chain) and an explicit count. And sense you want the result of the deepest recursion first, consing running average onto an acumulator as you recure gives you the right final order.

```
(define (successiveAvg Lst)
  (cond ((null? Lst) 
         (error "succesiveAvg requires a non-empty list"))
        ((fold (lambda (acc x) 
                   (if acc (number? x) #f))
                #t
                Lst)
         (error "succesiveAvg requires a list of numbers" Lst))
       (else
        (let ((inc (lambda (x) 
                      (+ 1 x)))
              (f (lambda (x) 
                    (lambda (y) (+ x y)))))
           (let loop ((acc '()) 
                      (c (lambda (x) x)) 
                      (L lst)
                      (i 1))
              (if (null? L) 
                  acc
                  (loop (cons (/ (c (car L)) i)
                              acc)
                         (f (c (car L)))
                         (cdr L)
                         (inc i))))))))

(successiveavg '(2 3 4 5 6))

;Value 3: (4 7/2 3 5/2 2)
```